# How to update android build on expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have develop a react native app using expo and make android build using expo build:android command but I recently make changes in my app now what should I do to update my build so that I can download newer version apk of my app. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

In the Expo [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps#7-update-your-app) you can find the section that talks about changing app version, etc. Check that out

Comment: if I change my app version from app.json then use expo publish command will my build be updated?

Comment: If you didn´t changed the app icon or name you dont even need to change app version, you just publis it and it should update for everyone that has installed the app

Comment: The expected behavior is this one [https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/offline-support.html] , did you restarted the app ?

Comment: Welp that seems like an expo error, or maybe something else, i've been using expo a long time and never ran in this error, try posting it in the official forums [https://forums.expo.io/]